# Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4

I'm new on laravel.

How do I run this query on laravel?

```
SELECT a.id, active, name, email, IFNULL(b.Total, 0) AS leads
FROM users AS a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, count(*) as Total
  FROM lead_user
  GROUP BY user_id
) AS b
ON a.id= b.user_id
WHERE is_deleted = 0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well, since you have the query already written...

```
DB::statement('
    SELECT a.id, active, name, email, IFNULL(b.Total, 0) AS leads
    FROM users AS a
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT user_id, count(*) as Total
      FROM lead_user
      GROUP BY user_id
    ) AS b
    ON a.id= b.user_id
    WHERE is_deleted = 0
');
```

[Here are the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/database)